# What makes this line of code execute?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, static-methods

What makes this line of code execute?

The code gives an output of 11, but I was expecting 
it to be 1

```
package methodcalling;

public class MethodCalling {

public static int cakes = 1;
public final static int UNIT = 10;
static{cakes += UNIT;}      // what makes this line of code execute

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(cakes);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static block is executed as the class gets loaded (i.e. directly after static variables are initialized). Therefore `cakes += UNIT;` is executed before `main`.